# could not find job trying to async and poll tasks

Tags: ansible

I try to do :

- Get a list of docker containers
- Shutdown this list (with async values to go to next task without waiting for the end).
- Waiting for shutdown

  I did this :

  ```
  - name: "get containers"
    become: yes
    shell: docker ps -a | grep -v NAMES | awk '{print $NF}'
    register: efluidnet_tp_containers_list
    delegate_to: myserver

  - name: "shutdown containers"
    async: 3600
    poll: 0
    become: yes
    docker_container:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: stopped
    with_items:
    - "{{ efluidnet_tp_containers_list.stdout_lines }}"
    register: restart_aelnet
    delegate_to: myserver

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item['ansible_job_id'] }}"
    with_items: "{{ restart_aelnet['results'] }}"

  - name: 'waiting for shutdown'
    async_status:
      jid: "{{ item['ansible_job_id'] }}"
    register: job_result
    until: job_result.finished
    retries: 30
    with_items: "{{ restart_aelnet['results'] }}"
    delegate_to: myserver
  ```

But my waiting task is unable to find the ansible_jod id :

```
TASK [get containers] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 05 December 2019  08:17:55 +0100 (0:00:00.285)       0:00:00.366 *****
changed: [localhost -> None]

TASK [shutdown containers] **************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 05 December 2019  08:17:56 +0100 (0:00:00.937)       0:00:01.303 *****
changed: [localhost -> None] => (item=ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-AMN_V13)
changed: [localhost -> None] => (item=ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SCH_V13)
changed: [localhost -> None] => (item=ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SAR_V13)
changed: [localhost -> None] => (item=ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-ROM_V13)
changed: [localhost -> None] => (item=ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SAL_V13)

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 05 December 2019  08:18:00 +0100 (0:00:03.320)       0:00:04.624 *****
ok: [localhost] => (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'264488569945.120415', 'failed': False, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'item': u'ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-AMN_V13', u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/264488569945.120415'}) => {
    "msg": "264488569945.120415"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'828045810515.120527', 'failed': False, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'item': u'ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SCH_V13', u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/828045810515.120527'}) => {
    "msg": "828045810515.120527"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'406259878781.120644', 'failed': False, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'item': u'ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SAR_V13', u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/406259878781.120644'}) => {
    "msg": "406259878781.120644"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'803234566504.120755', 'failed': False, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'item': u'ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-ROM_V13', u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/803234566504.120755'}) => {
    "msg": "803234566504.120755"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'966123972732.120860', 'failed': False, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'item': u'ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SAL_V13', u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/966123972732.120860'}) => {
    "msg": "966123972732.120860"
}

TASK [waiting for shutdown] **************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 05 December 2019  08:18:00 +0100 (0:00:00.085)       0:00:04.710 *****
failed: [localhost -> None] (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'264488569945.120415', 'failed': False, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'item': u'ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-AMN_V13', u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/264488569945.120415'}) => {"ansible_job_id": "264488569945.120415", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 1, "changed": false, "finished": 1, "item": {"ansible_job_id": "264488569945.120415", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "failed": false, "finished": 0, "item": "ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-AMN_V13", "results_file": "/root/.ansible_async/264488569945.120415", "started": 1}, "msg": "could not find job", "started": 1}
failed: [localhost -> None] (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'828045810515.120527', 'failed': False, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'item': u'ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SCH_V13', u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/828045810515.120527'}) => {"ansible_job_id": "828045810515.120527", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 1, "changed": false, "finished": 1, "item": {"ansible_job_id": "828045810515.120527", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "failed": false, "finished": 0, "item": "ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SCH_V13", "results_file": "/root/.ansible_async/828045810515.120527", "started": 1}, "msg": "could not find job", "started": 1}
failed: [localhost -> None] (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'406259878781.120644', 'failed': False, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'item': u'ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SAR_V13', u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/406259878781.120644'}) => {"ansible_job_id": "406259878781.120644", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 1, "changed": false, "finished": 1, "item": {"ansible_job_id": "406259878781.120644", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "failed": false, "finished": 0, "item": "ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SAR_V13", "results_file": "/root/.ansible_async/406259878781.120644", "started": 1}, "msg": "could not find job", "started": 1}
failed: [localhost -> None] (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'803234566504.120755', 'failed': False, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'item': u'ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-ROM_V13', u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/803234566504.120755'}) => {"ansible_job_id": "803234566504.120755", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 1, "changed": false, "finished": 1, "item": {"ansible_job_id": "803234566504.120755", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "failed": false, "finished": 0, "item": "ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-ROM_V13", "results_file": "/root/.ansible_async/803234566504.120755", "started": 1}, "msg": "could not find job", "started": 1}
failed: [localhost -> None] (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'966123972732.120860', 'failed': False, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'item': u'ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SAL_V13', u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/966123972732.120860'}) => {"ansible_job_id": "966123972732.120860", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 1, "changed": false, "finished": 1, "item": {"ansible_job_id": "966123972732.120860", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "failed": false, "finished": 0, "item": "ael-13.20.200-PREPRO-SAL_V13", "results_file": "/root/.ansible_async/966123972732.120860", "started": 1}, "msg": "could not find job", "started": 1}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I managed to run this mechanism with a simple example like this:

```
  - name: 'waiting for a long tasks'
    shell: /bin/sleep 15
    async: 1000
    poll: 0
    register: yum_sleeper
    delegate_to: myserver

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ yum_sleeper }}"
    delegate_to: myserver

  - name: 'get results'
    async_status:
      jid: "{{ yum_sleeper.ansible_job_id }}"
    register: job_result
    until: job_result.finished
    retries: 30
    delegate_to: myserver
```

But in my real use case i have a "results" properties that can be problematic ...

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is on `become`. To check the async_status the user needs to be the same as the one who ran the async job.

```
- name: 'waiting for shutdown'
  become: yes
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ item['ansible_job_id'] }}"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 30
  with_items: "{{ restart_aelnet['results'] }}"
  delegate_to: myserver
```